# How to copy a whole section (input texts, dropdown value,) all togther in one line with javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, copy, copy-paste

I want to create a program where my colleagues can input some number then issue name then product name, quantity, resolution given and can copy all these things to the clipboard in single line.

Ex:.
1234 // Damaged // Dell laptop // Q-1 // Repairing slot given //

I want this line to be copied with a button clicked and the values can be changes by the user.

This is code, but the problem is I have to give different ids to the elements and also it is copied seprately.

```
function copyToClipBoard() {

    var content = document.getElementById('textArea');
    
    content.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');

    alert("Copied!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value out of the textarea element using `element.value` and then call the `writeText()` function on `navigator.clipboard` passing it the value of the element.

example:

```
  function copyToClipBoard() {
    var element = document.getElementById('textArea');
    var content = element.value

    navigator.clipboard.writeText(content);
  }
```